# doctrine2 select specific columns

Tags: select, doctrine-orm, dql

In mysql, we can return specific result like as:

```
select  name,lastName from users where id=1;
```

how use the same request in doctrine2?
I khnow that we can use

$query=$this->_em->createQuery('select a.name, a.lastName from ...:Users a'); but i search some methods to user it  without a.name

for examlpe

`$query=$this->_em->createQuery('select name, lastName from ...:Users ');` is correct?

it's possible to return just the name and the lastname from a table without the prefix a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select some specific fields from the database you need to use the **partial** keyword.

Taken from the [doctrine partial object documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#partial-object-syntax) your query should look like:

```
$query=$this->_em->createQuery('SELECT partial u.{name, lastName} from Users u');
```

This will return an array of partially loaded User objects.